# How to get fzf.vim ignore node_modules and .git folders?

Tags: vim, fzf

I have fzf setup in vim with barely any customisation:

```
" fzf and ripgrep settings
set rtp+=/usr/local/opt/fzf
let g:fzf_action = {
    \ 'ctrl-t': 'tab split',
    \ 'ctrl-i': 'split',
    \ 'ctrl-s': 'vsplit'
    \ }
```

In my `.bash_profile`, I set the environment variable `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` to show hidden, but ignore `node_modules` and `.git`:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='rg --files --follow --no-ignore-vcs --hidden -g "!{node_modules/*,.git/*}"'
```

However, when I use `:Files` function in vim, it still searches in the folders i want ignored.

Comment: What you have done is for the command line, to use it for vim you need to to create a new command in ~/.vimrc

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim ?

Answer (score 26):

Have you tried `:GFiles` command?

It is one of the best FZF command that is excluding anything that is in .gitignore.

Personally I like to use it as default.

```
:help fzf-vim-commands
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect. `:GFiles` list all files that are added in the git repo. New files which have not been added yet will not show up.

Comment: Most of the time, I know where I'm creating files, and/or I have them in `:Buffers`. Those 2 commands are solving for me 99.999% of cases related to the question.

Comment: Sure, same for me! I use `:Files` when I want to look at some generated/built-in artifact

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Is it possible to parametrize `git ls-files` so that it shows everything except ignored files?

Comment: I tried `fzf --help`, I don't see any option called `GFiles` or `:GFiles`. Also I opened vim(using spacevim) and typed `:GFiles`, I dont see any command like that. Can you elaborate more instead of simply specifying `:GFiles`

Comment: This is about fzf vim plugin https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim, not about fzf command line utility.

Answer (score 23):

You can ignore the node_modules (and any other folder you want to ignore) by using a custom FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND. I use something like this:

(place it in your vimrc)

`let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='find . \( -name node_modules -o -name .git \) -prune -o -print'`

Comment: this is my favourite solution out of all listed and worked straight away

Comment: Unlike the answer marked as correct, this solution respects the current directory instead of listing from the root of the repository

Answer (score 8):

Silly me. I forgot to `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Bro, you're not alone! haha

Comment: I suggest you mark this as the accepted answer or update your question with it. Otherwise this answer could easily be overlooked, given the low number of upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose 'junegunn/fzf' are we tolking about.
I have success on make fzf and rg work for my need. (I'm a developer)
this is my vim 8.2 configuration:

```
command! -bang -nargs=* Rg
  \ call fzf#vim#grep(
  \   "rg -g '!design/' -g '!dist/' -g '!pnpm-lock.yaml' -g '!.git' -g '!node_modules' --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case ".shellescape(<q-args>), 1,
  \   fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': '--exact --delimiter : --nth 4..'}), <bang>0)
```

In this configuration inside last row `--exact` remove all fuzzy search: how developer I like exatc metch more

to not include folder and file I do not like I use `-g` option:

`rg -g '!design/' -g '!dist/' -g '!pnpm-lock.yaml' -g '!.git' -g '!node_modules'`

The `!` is to exclude
I'm excluding *design*, *dist* folder from my search base path (current directory)
and exclude il file *pnpm-lock.yaml* anywhare
and excluse *.git* and *node_modules* anywhare (file or folder)

hope can help,
regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your shell profile:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='fd --type f --strip-cwd-prefix --hidden --follow --exclude .git'
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)

It allows you to use default $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND if defined.

If you are using vim-plug for plugin management, to install fzf.vim:

```
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it results in:

```sh
command failed: rg --files ...
```

It is because it results from an `rg` error or you do not have it installed, for that you just have to execute

```sh
sudo apt install ripgrep -y
```

In case you use a script for the installation you can use:

```sh
which rg >/dev/null 2>&1 ||
    apt install ripgrep -y
```